# How to inject mouse event in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I have a script in `JMeter` that is executing more than the timeout specified in my application. I can not  increase the timeout of my application. 
I was wondering if there is a way to inject `mousehover / mousemove` event in my `JMeter` scripts which will keep the screen active and not get timed out.

When I manually execute the `JMeter` script I don't get the timeout because during the manual execution button clicks are getting captured as `event`, which it seems are not happening during the `jmeter` run(with multiple scripts).

Could you please assist in this issue.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Does mousehover / mousemove generate any HTTP request/response? If yes, record it in JMeter, just like any other HTTP request. If not, then this is not what is keeping the session alive in the browser. Basically your JMeter script should be an exact replica of the HTTP traffic coming from your browser. Sounds like you are missing some HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You have to observe the http operation that is invoked by the mouse hover.

Try to record it with Jmeter Proxy or with some other browser recorder (i.e. Firefox + Httpfox). Then you can repeat the operation.

IMHO, however, most of the time a "mouse over" is only managed at the display interface level, without back-end involvement. Check with your dev department if there is a dummy operation that restarts the timer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to post request with the help of HTTP request sampler then we don't have such kind of (mouse hover/mouse move) events but you can accomplish your requirement by providing timeout duration. For example I have given timeout of 5 minutes in below shown screenshot. You can increase or decrease as per you requirement
[image]

Check this [link](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) and read about `Connection and Response timeout`

Comment: Those timeouts are related to how long JMeter will wait for connection or response. They have nothing to do with the timeout application has. Person asking should not be altering them, it's unnecessary and could be harmful too (connections that linger for too long may eventually cause failures / OOM and so on)